# Ext js 4.2.3 beta - offline app locale on safari

Tags: javascript, extjs, safari, beta

I have a web app which has no of Ext js components. When i deploy webapp at server and use it via http:// everything runs fine. But when i use it offline using file:// protocol, locale is not being honored. Default Strings are always shown.
Any ideas?? I am using safari on mac and there are no cross domain xhr request limitations in safari. Need to load app in japanese :-(

Answer (score 1):

Ext needs Ajax to work so http:// protocol is required. I won't work over file://